# Can I send JSON Parameters contains non-English (Arabic) Characters in ionic 4 HTTP GET Header without using encoding?

Tags: c#, angular, ionic4

My API is selecting some filtered data from database

**My TS :**

```
getItems(fromId: string, os_params: any) {
        //    var encodedJSON =encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(os_params))
        var httpOptions = null;
        if (os_params) {
            httpOptions = {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    //  'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    // 'Accept': 'application/json,text/*;q=0.99',
                    'OS_Params': JSON.stringify(os_params) //encodedJSON
                    //,'Authorizationx': 'os-auth-token'
                })
            };
        }
        return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/quate?key=${fromId}`, httpOptions);
    }
```

os_params is a json Parameter contains as a sample { "first_name":"عميل 1" } (filters)

the code is firing an exception (Unexpected end of input)

- When i change the value to English it works fine so i have to use encoding but also for that i have to change my C# Code that i need in somewhere else,
  so i'm really stuck

any help please ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching web i found that i can not send non-English characters without encoding so i had to decode it in my back-end code ,
i used HttpUtility.UrlDecode() in c# then Deserialized the result,
if any one has another answer please tell me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add this to your HTML page header section:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`